# Replace letters in math font

Tags: amsmath, font-encodings

How can I find the slots (like `{"01}`) in `\DeclareMathSymbol{}{\mathord}{Greekletters}{"01}`. Does anyone have a list of symbol numbers?

Comment: `texdoc encguide`  should show you `encguide.pdf`  base latex distribution, the encoding you are using there is OT1 and there is a table in the appendix.

Comment: Thank you @David can i chage \forall.